# How to show my custom modal when user is trying to sign up with same Gmail Account using oauth2.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, react-redux

I have successfully restricted the user from creating multiple accounts with oauth2.0. I just need to show my custom modal when user is trying to do so.

Comment: how is your redux state like?